# Youtube Embedded video in android webview does not fit to Screen issue

Tags: android, webview, youtube, screen, embedded-video

I hit an API and get a html content, which i populate in android Webview.

Sometimes HTML content might have a url of youtube video. But not necessarily all the time.

When this content is displayed on mobile screen on webview, Youtube video is displayed but it does not fit to mobile screen. It is displayed in the size that is seen on youtube website.

Do i need to enable some Javascript or some other setting on webview, to make it fit to screen, whenever it is apart of html content?